# Pillow installation not recognized in Django through Apache

Tags: django, apache, python-imaging-library

When deploying my project through Apache wsgi, using a virtualenv on Ubuntu Server VM,  I get the following on error on /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
ImportError: Photologue was unable to import Python Imaging Library. Please confirm it's installed and available on your current Python path.
```

Setup:

```
Django==1.6.6
django-photologue==2.3
Pillow==2.5.1
```

However, I have been able to run the project with the same configuration in Ubuntu Desktop VM (for development). For Ubuntu Server VM I followed the same procedure:

1. Installed dependent image libraries (libjpeg8-dev, etc) through apt-get
2. pip install pillow, in virtualenv, it showed --- JPEG support available
3. Ran this with no problems:

   - manage.py shell
   - from PIL import Image
   - im = Image.open("file.jpg")
   - im.show()
4. Used django's server with no problem, it showed the login screen:

   - manage.py runserver
5. For sanity's sake, I uninstalled pillow, running manage.py runserver showed the same import error. I reinstalled pillow and the error went away in the django server

Now, the issues arise when I try to access the website on the browser through apache. I go to the servername to get the actual django website and keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error on the browser and the import error on apache log.

The only thing I can think of is that in manage.py shell I can't do "import Image". However, photologue has a try/except import in which it will do "from PIL import Image" in case of an exception with "import Image", which covers that case.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, posting it here since it was not entirely obvious.

This is a more subtle case of PIL not being able to link against the directories in apt-get. The answer from the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751455&p=10811107#post10811107) solves this issue.

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /lib/
sudo ln - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/
```

However, I was not able to run the django proyect with pillow. I had to use PIL, which is annoying:

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```